# Unable to change the suggestions of AutoCompleteTextField

Tags: flutter

Problem Description -

I am writing a search widget which is an AutoCompletTextField. It takes the queryString entered by the user and fetches related suggestions from the internet and then attaches those suggestions to the AutoCompleteTextField. Everything till fetching the suggestions from the internet is working just fine. The suggestions are not popping up when I call the setState() method of the widget. The suggestions don't pop up even after the call to setState(). Please help.
Code -

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'miscellaneous_widgets.dart';
 import 'models/AppContextData.dart';
 import 'package:autocomplete_textfield/autocomplete_textfield.dart';
 import 'workers/MCAutoSuggestionsGetter.dart';`

class CompanySearchBox extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_CompanySearchBoxState createState() => _CompanySearchBoxState();
}

class _CompanySearchBoxState extends State<CompanySearchBox> {
GlobalKey<AutoCompleteTextFieldState<String>> key = 
GlobalKey<AutoCompleteTextFieldState<String>>();
List<String> lstSuggestions = List<String>();
TextEditingController companySearchBoxController = TextEditingController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
AutoCompleteTextField<String> myCompanySearchBox;
TextEditingController CompanyNameController = TextEditingController();
myCompanySearchBox = AutoCompleteTextField<String>(
  key: key,
  clearOnSubmit: false,
  style: TextFieldStyle.get(),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Search companies here.",
          //border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
        ),
  submitOnSuggestionTap: true,
  suggestions: lstSuggestions,
  textChanged: (queryString){
    if(queryString.length >= 3)
      queryCompanyNames(queryString);
  },
  itemBuilder: (context,item){
    return Center(
      heightFactor: 1,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            title: Text(
                item,
                style: TextRegularStyle.get()),
          ),
          Divider(color: Colors.blueGrey,)
      ],)
    );
  },
  itemFilter: (item,queryString ){
    if(item.toLowerCase().startsWith(queryString.toLowerCase()))
      return true;
  },
  itemSorter: (item1, item2){
    return item1.toLowerCase().compareTo(item2.toLowerCase());
  },
  itemSubmitted: (SelectedItem){
    //Not doing here anything as of now.
  },
  );
  //myCompanySearchBox.textField.controller = CompanyNameController,
  return myCompanySearchBox;
}

queryCompanyNames(String queryString) async
{
  /*Calling the MCAutoSuggestionsGetter which fetches the suggestions from the internet. This step is working fine. We are getting a List<String> in "Suggestions" variable below. But when setState() is called, the previous "lstSuggestions" should be cleared and new "Suggestions" should be added. And these newly added suggestions should be displayed. But I am unable to achieve this.*/

MCAutoSuggestionsGetter.fetchSuggestions(queryString).then((Suggestions){
    setState((){
      lstSuggestions.clear();
      lstSuggestions.addAll(Suggestions);
    });
  });
 }
}
```

My pubspec.yaml -

```
name: dev1_stock_meter
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.2.5+1
  firebase_auth: ^0.7.0
  fluttertoast: ^3.0.4
  autocomplete_textfield: ^1.6.4
  html: ^0.13.3+3
  http: ^0.12.0
  date_format: ^1.0.6

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
  sdk: flutter



flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

assets:
  - images/logo.jpg

fonts:
  - family: GoogleSans
    fonts:
      - asset: fonts/GoogleSans-Regular.ttf
        weight: 300
      - asset: fonts/GoogleSans-Bold.ttf
        weight: 400
```

Expected Behaviour:

The expected behaviour is when the user types a string that is more than 3 characters long, the suggestions should be fetched from internet and these suggestions should be attached to the AutoCompletTextField and the suggestions should be displayed.

Comment: What is the package you use for AutoCompleteTextField?

Comment: are you using `autocomplete_textfield` package?

Comment: Yes. this is the one I am using `autocomplete_textfield: ^1.6.4`.

Comment: @AbhijeetKharatmol You should show the packages you're using and also the imports, the code isn't runnable on my device this way

Comment: @AmmarAtef I have updated my code with packages and dependencies. Please have a look and please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I had the same trouble with this widget and it didn't get updated once the view is built it seems. Even though the suggestions list gets updated, results were not shown in list. So I tried `FutureBuilder` to fetch data and build the view. You may get an idea from https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html